# InputProps Material-UI in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

I have to make the `TextField` in material-ui to be uppercase. Right now, I need to put `inputProps={{ style: { textTransform: 'uppercase' } }}` in everything `TextField`. So I have define a theme in my react app for this and I wanted something to look like this.

Please also check picture on how I do them

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnukB.png

**MuiTextField.js**

```
export default {
  root: {
    textTransform: 'capitalize',
  },
};
```

Comment: Hi Joseph, I think you are on the right track here. You just have to wrap your top level component with `ThemeProvider` which will take your custom `theme` object as a parameter. For example refer - [Material UI example](https://material-ui.com/customization/theming/#custom-variables)

Comment: @jaybhatt. Yes, I did that. But my problem is when I start typing I need to transform the inputted text to uppercase.

Comment: So do you want the value to be uppercase everytime or do you want to only show that it's changing to uppercase for the sake of UI using the `textTransform` you did above?

Comment: @jaybhatt. Uppercase all the time

Comment: I think in that case the best you can do is create a generic handler which always changes value to uppercase and use it.

Comment: @jaybhatt. this works `inputProps={{ style: { textTransform: 'uppercase' } }}` but I need to declare it on the theme to be global.

Comment: Yes, so what is the problem with that? Like it should work fine right?

Comment: @jaybhatt. I want to declare it in the `theme` rather than putting that in every `TextField`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `theme` and override the `textTransform` to `capitalize` in every `MuiInputBase` class of your project, as below:

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiInputBase: {
      input: {
        textTransform: "uppercase"
      }
    }
  }
});
```

then wrap your project in a `ThemeProvider` and pass `theme` as a prop to the `ThemeProvider`:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <Demo />
  </ThemeProvider>,
  document.querySelector("#root")
);
```

[sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-jfq4e?file=/index.js)

Using this method, you no longer need to manually add `textTransform: "capitalize"` to every `TextField` component.

Comment: This doesn't work. You're codesandbox too doesn't capitalize.

Comment: sorry I updated the answer. Please check it and the link again. I changed `capitalize` to `uppercase` which is the correct value in this case